# SELECT CASE with COUNT no output when COUNT = 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count ads for different price ranges, but my query does not output when count is zero and thus I am unable to relate that to the range array.

Like this:

This is the array with the price breaks:

```
$arr_pri = array(1, 30000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 125000, 150000, 175000, 200000, 300000, 400000);
```

It here's the query:

```
$ctpri = count ($arr_pri);

$ctmod_pri = array();

$arr_i=$arr_k='';

$sql = "SELECT `range`, COUNT(`ad_id`) as ctads FROM (
        SELECT CASE ";
         for ($i=0; $i < $ctpri-1; $i++){
            $k=$i+1;
            $arr_i=$arr_pri[$i]+1;
            $arr_k=$arr_pri[$k];

$sql .= "WHEN price BETWEEN {$arr_i} AND {$arr_k} THEN CAST('{$i}' AS UNSIGNED) ";}

$sql .= " END AS `range`, ad_id FROM ads
WHERE published = 'Y'
AND deleted = 'N' ) AS t GROUP BY `range`";
$stmt = $ulink->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ctmod_pri[] = $r['ctads'];
}
```

A typical output for $ctmod_pri is:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I was expecting it to produce an array with 10 elements, one for each price range ( 0-30000, 30001-50000 ....), also outputting zero results.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `CASE` expression will never generate the missing values if no rows match, so there's nothing to "count 0 of."  But you're returning a column called "range" and then throwing it away.  Why don't you use it for mapping, instead of trying to take a shortcut and just get an array of ctads values?  Note also, you should always add `ORDER BY` if you expect a certain ordering.  `GROUP BY` sometimes sorts, but you should not depend on implicit but technically undefined ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael-sqlbot pointed out the CASE will not do what you want. I'm not entirely sure of the desired output but try this query.

```
SELECT '2-30000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 2 AND 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '30001-50000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 30001 AND 50000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '50001-75000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 50001 AND 75000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '75001-100000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 75001 AND 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '100001-125000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 100001 AND 125000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '125001-150000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 125001 AND 150000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '150001-175000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 150001 AND 175000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '175001-200000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 175001 AND 200000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '200001-300000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 200001 AND 300000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads
union
SELECT '300001-400000' AS `range`, SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 300001 AND 400000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ctads` FROM ads;
```

It will count the number of ads in the price range given. You can change the `2-30000` to 0 and so forth if that's the output you need.

The `THEN 1 else 0` basically means if the row satisfies the WHEN portion, it says add 1 otherwise add 0.

Comment: Thanks @David Fairbanks. I am accepting this as a solution, but I am somewhat disappointed on how verbose it is. Worse than that, it is very time consuming as well. I am considering just not to put that information on my app, all taken into account.